# Splitting a list<> that each item contains comma separated strings and formatting it out

Tags: c#, string, class, list, string-formatting

I have a simple class like this:

```
class QuickReport
{
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public string PinName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {            
        return DeviceName + "," + GroupName + "," + PinName;
    }
}
```

Later I make a list of items with this class:

```
List<QuickReport> QR = new List<QuickReport>();
```

Later in my program it will fill up and when I save it in a text file it will be like this example:

```
HBM\D1,GND,10
HBM\D1,GND,12
HBM\D1,NT_IOp,115
HBM\D1,NT_IOp,117
HBM\D2,GND,8
HBM\D2,NT_IOp,115
HBM\D2,NT_IOp,116
```

Now I want to make a function to save the text file in more readable manner. That is formatting it by DEVICE, GROUPS and PINS. So the above example would result in:

```
HBM\D1
GND: 10, 12
NT_IOp: 115, 117

HBM\D2
GND: 8
NT_IOp: 115, 116
```

can you please help and give some ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the `QuickReport` class contain a `List<String>` for the `GroupName` and `PinName` since there are potentially more than one per Device?

Comment: Have you made any progress yourself or are you looking for someone to provide you a complete solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = QR.ToLookup(i=>i.DeviceName, i => new {i.GroupName, i.PinName})
              .Select(i=> 
                     new {DeviceName = i.Key, 
                          Groups = i.ToLookup(g=>g.GroupName, g=>g.PinName)});

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach ( var device in query)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(device.DeviceName);
            foreach ( var gr in device.Groups)
            {
               sb.Append(gr.Key + ": ");
               sb.Append(String.Join(", ", gr.ToArray()));
               sb.AppendLine();
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        var stringToWrite = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

As i understand you have tree structure, where Device have child Groups, and Groups have child pins.
You can create custom classes like this:

```
class Group
{
    string Name;
    //pins that belong to this group
    List<string> pins; 
}

class Device
{
    string Name;
    //groups that belong to this device
    List<Group> Groups;
}
```

And than just collect it to `List<Device>` and serialize it using [XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't complete, but it should give you enough to go on.  You'll still need to add your newlines, and remove trailing commas, etc.

```
// Make your key the device name
var qrHash = new Dictionary<string, List<QuickReport>>();

// Populate your QR Dictionary here.

var output = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var keyValuePair in qrHash)
{
    output.Append(keyValuePair.Key);
    var gnd = new StringBuilder("GND: ");
    var nt = new StringBuilder("NT_IOp: ");

    foreach (var qr in keyValuePair.Value)
    {
        gnd.Append(qr.GroupName);
        nt.Append(qr.PinName);
    }

    output.Append(gnd);
    output.Append(nt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the XmlSerializer to serialize and deserialize your class? This should provide some readable output.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Comment: vah thats too though for me at the moment :P

Comment: It's pretty easy as far as I remember. Just look at the link for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest ways I can think of to do this would either be to loop over the List<> 3 times, eachtime checking on a seperate accessor, writing it out to a StringBuilder, then returning StringBuilder.ToString() from the function.

Or, you could use 3 stringbuilders to hold each accessor type, then push all 3 from the function on return.